# Remove Default Blogroll Links via Plugin script

Tags: plugin-development

I have a plugin that I use on all my new sites to set up site defaults (deletes the "hello world" post, the "about" page, the "Mr WordPress" comment, etc...)

I'd like to add a routine that removes all the default links under "Blogroll". I'm not sure what function to call. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested this yet, but it should do the trick in 3x:

```
// Get all the existing links
$arr_args = array( 'hide_invisible' => 0 );
$arr_links = get_bookmarks( $arr_args );

// Run through the list and delete 'em
foreach($arr_links as $obj_link) {
    wp_delete_link($obj_link->link_id);
}
```

Of course, you'd only want to do this once, and only on a fresh install as it deletes all links. Alternately, you could hardcode an array of default link slugs/ids and loop through that instead. Depends where and when you're running this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just "truncate wp_links" using wpdb. :-)

Comment: +1 - but don't forget about the term relationships first (and possibly even deleting the term 'blogroll' too?)

Comment: Denis, sounds interesting, can you elaborate a bit on how you would do this taking TheDeadMedic's comment into account?

Comment: Why would you mess with all this manually when Wordpress has a native function for deleting links? The function wp_delete_link() deletes a link and its relationships for you. It also cleans out the bookmark cache.

Comment: @MathSmath It was only that a raw query does everything in one swoop - but in hindsight, you're right. I'd combine the two solutions, `wp_delete_link()` to clear out the cache and term relations, then `TRUNCATE` to reset the table index :)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Digital high five.

Comment: @Scott: He's right. Another query would be needed to reset the terms count. As an aside the count gets reset when new bookmarks are added with those terms, though.

Comment: @MathSmath Oh yeah! @Denis If @Scott uses both methods, `wp_delete_link()` will sort out the term count.